# Node express - Uploading pdf with multer and axios creates empty pdf with [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, multer

When uploading a pdf with axios(client) and multer(server), the file makes it to the server. However, when I use `writeFileSync()`, it just creates a pdf with `[object, Object]` inside of it. Here's what the object like in req.file:

```
{
   fieldname: 'file',
   originalname: '307.pdf',
   encoding: '7bit',
   mimetype: 'application/pdf',
   buffer: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0d 25 e2 e3 cf d3 0d 0a 31 33 32 36 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0d 3c 3c 2f 4c 69 6e 65 61 72 69 7a 65 64 20 31 2f 4c 20 35 36 31 37 30 ... 561656 more bytes>,
   size: 561706
 }
```

I tried writing req.file.buffer to the pdf file, which does write more gibberish to the pdf, but it isn't properly encoded. Is there some encoding setting I'm missing somewhere?

**Client code:**

```
handle307Upload(e) {

    const dataForm = new FormData();
    dataForm.append('file', e.target.files[0]);

    axios.post('http://localhost:4001/importalpha', dataForm)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**Route code:**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

     const file  = req.file;
     fs.writeFileSync(join(__dirname, '307.pdf'), file);
}
```

**Server code: (removed some for brevity)**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const importAlphaRoute = require('../routes/import-alpha');

const upload = multer({});

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '5mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));

app.post('/importalpha', upload.single('file'), importAlphaRoute);
```

Comment: Why are you writing `req.file` and not `req.file.buffer`? What happens if you write `req.file.buffer`? Simply, in my opinion, everything should work anyway, if you write `buffer`.

Comment: @RustamD9RS as I stated in the OP, "I tried writing req.file.buffer to the pdf file, which does write more gibberish to the pdf, but it isn't properly encoded". In other words, it writes a pdf with a bunch of gibberish in it.

Answer (score 1):

For file upload using multer you need to write destination folder where you need to store your file

Update your code like this

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the pdf is actually uploading fine, I thought it it was gibberish but it's not. So I'll use this to explain why my code actually works.

I **am** able to write a file to disk using:

```
const upload = multer({});
```

I don't need to designate a path like `multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })` here since I'm saving with `fs.writeFileSync()` instead of using the built-in multer functionality.

Once the form object is sent to the server, I'm able to write the pdf to disk using the buffer property of the file object, like so:

```
 fs.writeFileSync(join(__dirname, '307.pdf'), file.buffer);
```

I mention this (file.buffer) in the OP, whereas I thought it wasn't writing the pdf file correctly at this point, however it was in fact creating the pdf properly.